# Is there a JSX shortcut for assigning a value to a property when it has the same name?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If I'm writing some JSX, is there a shortcut for some like this:

```
<MyComponent myProperty={myProperty} />
```

Such that I don't have to write `myProperty` twice?

I'm basically looking for a JSX equivalent to the literal object shorthand syntax in ES2015 and higher.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such equivalent. The reason is that JSX mimics HTML syntax and for HTML both the following have a meaning:

```
// a property without value
<MyComponent myProperty />
// a property with a value
<MyComponent myProperty={myProperty} />
```

Therefore no shorthand syntax can be introduced.

You could use pure JS though:

```
 React.createElement("MyComponent", { myProperty });
```

or, you can pass all properties as a JS object:

```
<MyComponent {...{ myProperty }} />
```

I belive that both would decrease readability.

Comment: strictly speaking, first case is `truthy` so not entirely w/o a value and useful for `PropTypes.bool` - so you don't have to say `myProperty={true}` - conversely, lack of `myProperty` is falsy.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I know, that's what it means in HTML, e.g. `<input hidden>`

Comment: That makes sense. However, I don't see any ambiguity inherent in `<MyComponent {myProperty} />`